# A single checkbox input incorrectly passing the value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

I've spent a few hours looking at all the relevant answers here and I'm still not able to figure out why this is happening.

I'm trying to capture a yes/no type of answer from the users.

I'm using following checkbox input. I could use radio buttons and possibly make it work, but there is a reason I want it to be a single check box user interface.

PROBLEM: No matter whether I check or uncheck the checkbox a '0' is always passed to the server. When I check the checkbox I expect '1'.

html :

```
<input type="hidden" name="hardtofind" id="hardtofindField" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="hardtofind" id="hardtofindField" value="1">I'm having hard time finding information I'm looking for<br>
<input type="button" id="submitButton" class="rbutton" value="Submit">
```

jquery:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#submitButton").click(function(event){
var hardtofind = jQuery("#hardtofindField").val();
jQuery.ajax({
url : "../send_form_email.php",
data : {
"hardtofind" : hardtofind,     
},
method : "GET",
success : function(){
jQuery("#submitButton").hide();
jQuery("#successMsg").show();
}
});
event.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
```

php:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['hardtofind']) && !empty($_GET['hardtofind']) ){
$hardtofind = $_GET['hardtofind']; 
}
```

UPDATE:

Thanks for pointing out the duplicate ids. I introduced that problem while trying to fix the original problem.

When I remove the hidden filed (so no duplicate IDs). I'm still stuck with the same problem where it always passes '1' now.

What do I need to change so that when the single checkbox is unchecked it passes '0' and when checked '1'?

new html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="hardtofind" id="hardtofindField" value="1">I'm having hard time finding information I'm looking for<br>
<input type="button" id="submitButton" class="rbutton" value="Submit">
```

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery is picking up this element, as it is the first match:

```
<input type="hidden" name="hardtofind" id="hardtofindField" value="0">
```

...which has a value of 0, and sending that to the server.

Use a different id in order to get the expected result.